# Dynamic Columns in SQL Query with count and join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2:
Table "Phases:

```
Phases_ID   Phases_Title
------------------------
1           Phase1
2           Phase2
...         ...
```

and Table "Milestones"

```
Milestones_ID  Milestones_PhaseID  Milestones_Category
------------------------------------------------------
1              1                   Project
2              1                   Project
3              1                   Customer
...            ...                 ...
```

You can see this is a 1:n relation between the tables.

Now i need a query with a result something like that:

```
Phases_ID   Project     Customer   (Columns 'Project' and 'Customer' counts milestones)
---------------------------------
1           2           1             
2           0           3
...         ...         ...
```

Is there a possibility to create the Columns with the Milestone Categories dynamically?
Otherwise i will do a simple left join over the tables and do the rest in code behind, but the performance will be the worst.

Thanks!

Comment: Do [pivots](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! `PIVOT` to the rescue: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Phases_ID, Project, Customer
FROM (
    SELECT Phases_ID, Milestones_PhaseID, Milestones_Category
    FROM Phases INNER JOIN Milestones ON Phases_ID = Milestones_PhaseID
) AS src
PIVOT (
    COUNT(*)
    FOR Milestones_Category IN ([Project], [Customer])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect example. That was it :-)